# Compiling application using RTSCom / Windows Pen API with mingw application

Tags: winapi, mingw, msys2, stylus-pen

I'm working on a GTK+ note taking application that heavily uses the stylus as an input. The stylus support in GTK+ is sadly really bad on Windows. (i.e. only Wacom pens are detected, excluding Surface devices). 
I'm currently trying integrating the Windows Pen API from the Windows SDK into the application and have failed compiling the application as the header files seem to be incompatible with mingw.

I've successfully linked g++ against the header files in `C/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Include`, but I get various errors.

For example:

```
C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Include/10.0.17763.0/shared/wtypes.h:745:26: error: pasting "/" and "/" does not give a valid preprocessing token
  745 | #define _VARIANT_BOOL    /##/
```

Is there any easy fix or do I need to compile the header files using the windows compile utility?

Comment: You should use MinGW's [win32api](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/MinGW/Base/w32api/) package if you're using MinGW.

Comment: Sadly this doesn't contain the RTSCom API